# Extract a selected file from a .tbz file

Tags: centos, tar, extract

I am on CentOS server. I have to download a .tbz file every day which is of 3GB in size and then i have to extract it and use inner files for further process.

There are 48 files in the .tbz extracted folder and i have to use only one file from it. After extraction size of the folder is approx. 25 GB because of which disk space of server get exhausted.

I tried

```
tar -xjf /var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3/price.tbz total_price
```

and

```
tar xjf /var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3/price.tbz total_price -C /var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

and

```
tar -xjf /var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3/price.tbz --wildcards --no-anchored 'total_price*'
```

where total_price is the name of the file inside it. But above command says :

```
tar: total_price: Not found in archive
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Any idea what i am missing?

Comment: Duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/342229/extract-a-selected-file-from-a-tbz-file

Comment: its my question only. Posted on server fault because i am not getting exact answer over here!

Comment: Ask for the question to be moved from here to there. Likely one of these questions will be closed soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it worked for me by the command:

```
tar --extract --file=/var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3/price.tbz price/total_price
```

which extracted the file inside the folder price.

Comment: or to use other standard options,

tar -xvjf --file=/path/to/filename.tbz filename/desired_item

i think the takeaway is that you need to include the base filename (i.e. no extension) in the output path since the directory originally was compressed that way.

Answer (score 1):

For extraction, you have to use one or more filenames as output by `tar -tf price.tbz`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here total_price is the is file name i want to extract from the .tbz archive. i tried it with the options -tf but same error message came as i wrote above.